# How to update a tableview's cell based on values from other cells using MVVM/RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm new to RxSwift and trying to learn by creating a simple signup form. I want to implement it using a `UITableView` (as an exercise, plus it will become more complicated in the future) so I'm currently using two types of cells:

- A `TextInputTableViewCell` with just a `UITextField`
- A `ButtonTableViewCell` with just a `UIButton`

In order to represent each cell, I created an enum which looks like that:

```
enum FormElement {
    case textInput(placeholder: String, text: String?)
    case button(title: String, enabled: Bool)
}
```

and use it in a `Variable` to feed the tableview:

```
    formElementsVariable = Variable<[FormElement]>([
        .textInput(placeholder: "username", text: nil),
        .textInput(placeholder: "password", text: nil),
        .textInput(placeholder: "password, again", text: nil),
        .button(title: "create account", enabled: false)
        ])
```

by binding like that:

```
    formElementsVariable.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) {
            (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: FormElement) in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            switch element {
            case .textInput(let placeholder, let defaultText):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextInputTableViewCell
                cell.textField.placeholder = placeholder
                cell.textField.text = defaultText
                return cell
            case .button(let title, let enabled):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonTableViewCell
                cell.button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
                cell.button.isEnabled = enabled
                return cell
            }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

So far, so good - this is how my form looks like:

[image]

Now, the actual problem I'm facing here, is **how am I supposed to enable the *create account* button when all the 3 text inputs are not empty and the password is the same in both password textfields**? In other words, what is the right way to apply changes to a cell, based on events happening on one or more of the other cells?

Should my goal be to change this `formElementsVariable` through the ViewModel or is there any better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Comment: I tried this way to create my sign up form with RXSwift and MVVM but the number of lines of code and the complexity got increased So I left that idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest that you change your ViewModel a bit such that you can have more control over the changes in the textfields. If you create streams from your input fields such as username, password and confirmation, you can subscribe for the changes and react to it in any way you want.

Here is how I restructured your code a bit for working with changes in text fields.

```
internal enum FormElement {
    case textInput(placeholder: String, variable: Variable<String>)
    case button(title: String)
}
```

ViewModel.

```
internal class ViewModel {

    let username = Variable("")
    let password = Variable("")
    let confirmation = Variable("")

    lazy var formElementsVariable: Driver<[FormElement]> = {
        return Observable<[FormElement]>.of([.textInput(placeholder: "username",
                                                          variable: username),
                                               .textInput(placeholder: "password",
                                                          variable: password),
                                               .textInput(placeholder: "password, again",
                                                          variable: confirmation),
                                               .button(title: "create account")])
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
    }()

    lazy var isFormValid: Driver<Bool> = {
        let usernameObservable = username.asObservable()
        let passwordObservable = password.asObservable()
        let confirmationObservable = confirmation.asObservable()

        return Observable.combineLatest(usernameObservable,
                                        passwordObservable,
                                        confirmationObservable) { [unowned self] username, password, confirmation in
                                            return self.validateFields(username: username,
                                                                       password: password,
                                                                       confirmation: confirmation)
            }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)
    }()

    fileprivate func validateFields(username: String,
                                    password: String,
                                    confirmation: String) -> Bool {

        guard username.count > 0,
            password.count > 0,
            password == confirmation else {
                return false
        }

        // do other validations here

        return true
    }
}
```

ViewController,

```
internal class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    fileprivate var viewModel = ViewModel()

    fileprivate let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel.formElementsVariable.drive(tableView.rx.items) { [unowned self] (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: FormElement) in

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

                switch element {

                case .textInput(let placeholder, let variable):

                    let cell = self.createTextInputCell(at: indexPath,
                                                        placeholder: placeholder)

                    cell.textField.text = variable.value
                    cell.textField.rx.text.orEmpty
                        .bind(to: variable)
                        .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
                    return cell

                case .button(let title):
                    let cell = self.createButtonCell(at: indexPath,
                                                     title: title)
                    self.viewModel.isFormValid.drive(cell.button.rx.isEnabled)
                        .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
                    return cell
                }
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    fileprivate func createTextInputCell(at indexPath:IndexPath,
                                         placeholder: String) -> TextInputTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! TextInputTableViewCell
        cell.textField.placeholder = placeholder
        return cell
    }

    fileprivate func createButtonCell(at indexPath:IndexPath,
                                      title: String) -> ButtonInputTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonInputTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! ButtonInputTableViewCell
        cell.button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        return cell
    }
}
```

We have three different variables based on which we enable disable button, you can see the power of stream and rx operators here.

I think it is always good to convert plain properties to Rx when they change a lot like username, password and passwordField in our case. You can see that formElementsVariable do not change much, it has no real added value of Rx except the magical tableview binding for creating cell.

Comment: I've been tracking this question for last 3 days. I was also trying to give the answer and my answer was a lot same but got stuck in one part. But you have done a good job. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are the missing the appropriate `rx` properties inside the `FormElement` that will enable you to bind UI events to the validations you want to perform within the ViewModel.

To begin with the `FormElement`, the `textInput` should expose a *text* `Variable` and the `button` an *enabled* `Driver`. I made this distinction to showcase that in the first case you want to consume UI events while in the second you just want to update the UI.

```
enum FormElement {
   case textInput(placeholder: String, text: Variable<String?>)
   case button(title: String, enabled:Driver<Bool>, tapped:PublishRelay<Void>)
}
```

I took the liberty of adding a *tapped* event that will enable you to perform your business logic when the button if finally enabled!

Moving on to the `ViewModel`, I exposed only what the `View` needs to know but internally I applied all the necessary operators:

```
class FormViewModel {

    // what ViewModel exposes to view
    let formElementsVariable: Variable<[FormElement]>
    let registerObservable: Observable<Bool>

    init() {
        // form element variables, the middle step that was missing...
        let username = Variable<String?>(nil) // docs says that Variable will deprecated and you should use BehaviorRelay...
        let password = Variable<String?>(nil) 
        let passwordConfirmation = Variable<String?>(nil)
        let enabled: Driver<Bool> // no need for Variable as you only need to emit events (could also be an observable)
        let tapped = PublishRelay<Void>.init() // No need for Variable as there is no need for a default value

        // field validations
        let usernameValidObservable = username
            .asObservable()
            .map { text -> Bool in !(text?.isEmpty ?? true) }

        let passwordValidObservable = password
            .asObservable()
            .map { text -> Bool in text != nil && !text!.isEmpty && text!.count > 5 }

        let passwordConfirmationValidObservable = passwordConfirmation
            .asObservable()
            .map { text -> Bool in text != nil && !text!.isEmpty && text!.count > 5 }

        let passwordsMatchObservable = Observable.combineLatest(password.asObservable(), passwordConfirmation.asObservable())
            .map({ (password, passwordConfirmation) -> Bool in
                password == passwordConfirmation
            })

        // enable based on validations
        enabled = Observable.combineLatest(usernameValidObservable, passwordValidObservable, passwordConfirmationValidObservable, passwordsMatchObservable)
            .map({ (usernameValid, passwordValid, passwordConfirmationValid, passwordsMatch) -> Bool in
                usernameValid && passwordValid && passwordConfirmationValid && passwordsMatch // return true if all validations are true
            })
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)

        // now that everything is in place, generate the form elements providing the ViewModel variables
        formElementsVariable = Variable<[FormElement]>([
            .textInput(placeholder: "username", text: username),
            .textInput(placeholder: "password", text: password),
            .textInput(placeholder: "password, again", text: passwordConfirmation),
            .button(title: "create account", enabled: enabled, tapped: tapped)
            ])

        // somehow you need to subscribe to register to handle for button clicks...
        // I think it's better to do it from ViewController because of the disposeBag and because you probably want to show a loading or something
        registerObservable = tapped
            .asObservable()
            .flatMap({ value -> Observable<Bool> in
                // Business login here!!!
                NSLog("Create account!!")
                return Observable.just(true)
            })
    }
}
```

Finally, on your `View`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var formViewModel: FormViewModel = FormViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TextInputTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextInputTableViewCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ButtonTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ButtonTableViewCell")

        // view subscribes to ViewModel observables...
        formViewModel.registerObservable.subscribe().disposed(by: disposeBag)

        formViewModel.formElementsVariable.asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) {
                (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: FormElement) in
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
                switch element {
                case .textInput(let placeholder, let defaultText):
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextInputTableViewCell
                    cell.textField.placeholder = placeholder
                    cell.textField.text = defaultText.value
                    // listen to text changes and pass them to viewmodel variable
                    cell.textField.rx.text.asObservable().bind(to: defaultText).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                    return cell
                case .button(let title, let enabled, let tapped):
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonTableViewCell
                    cell.button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
                    // listen to viewmodel variable changes and pass them to button
                    enabled.drive(cell.button.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                    // listen to button clicks and pass them to the viewmodel
                    cell.button.rx.tap.asObservable().bind(to: tapped).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                    return cell
                }
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope I helped!

PS. I am mainly an Android developer but I found your question (and bounty) intriguing so please forgive any rough edges with (rx)swift

Comment: Nice answer but you need to have a dispose bag for your cell (see mistake #3: http://adamborek.com/top-7-rxswift-mistakes/). An improvement to avoid the optional strings is to bind `cell.textField.rx.text.orEmpty` which replaces nil by an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, the inline comments help a lot! I had to accept the other answer though, since it's pretty similar and had more upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You would do better to emit table data all at once rather than one row at a time because otherwise you can't really distinguish between a) is this next event a new row or b) is this next event a refresh of a row I already showed.

Given that here's one way to do it.  This would go in the ViewModel and present the table data as an observable.  You can then bind the text fields for the username/password to the properties (behavior relays) though probably nicer to not expose them as such to the UI (hide behind properties)

```
var userName = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
var password1 = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
var password2 = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

struct LoginTableValues {
    let username: String
    let password1: String
    let password2: String
    let createEnabled: Bool
}

func tableData() -> Observable<LoginTableValues> {
    let createEnabled = Observable.combineLatest(userName.asObservable(), password1.asObservable(), password2.asObservable())
        .map { (username: String, password1: String, password2: String) -> Bool in
            return !username.isEmpty &&
                !password1.isEmpty &&
                password1 == password2
        }

    return Observable.combineLatest(userName.asObservable(), password1.asObservable(), password2.asObservable(), createEnabled)
        .map { (arg: (String, String, String, Bool)) -> LoginTableValues in
            let (username, password1, password2, createEnabled) = arg
            return LoginTableValues(username: username, password1: password1, password2: password2, createEnabled: createEnabled)
        }
}
```

Comment: `BehaviorRelay`s should be declared with `let`. On every change in one of the fields, there will be a `next` event for the `Observable` returned by `tableData()` resulting in the tableview cells being reloaded every time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it provides an alternative solution that others didn't consider!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you may want to try `RxDataSources` which is an RxSwift wrapper for TableViews. Secondly, to answer your question, I would have done the change through the ViewModel- that is, provide a ViewModel for the cell and then in the ViewModel set an observable that will handle the validation. When all of that is setup, do a `combineLatest` on all the cell's validation observables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I considered using `RxDataSources` but it seemed to be for cases where I need more complicated operations (like adding/removing cells), so I thought I'd keep it simple. Regarding the rest of your answer, I would really appreciate it if you could provide some sample code / references to something similar you might have seen online. Thanks!